# Accessing keys from an hash whose values are arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have the following hash:

```
@types = {"source-1"=>["type1", "type2"], "source-2"=>["type3", "type4"]}
```

I am doing the following in my haml :

```
%ul
      - @types.values.flatten.each do |type|
        - if @sources.include? type
          %input#types{:name => "types[]", :type => "checkbox", :value=> "#{type}", checked: :true, readonly: "readonly"}/
          %label{:for => "types"} "#{type}"
        - else
          %input#types{:name => "types[]", :type => "checkbox", :value=> "#{type}"}/
          %label{:for => "types"} "#{type}"
```

Doing this helps me display the different types appropriately with checkboxes. I want to include an extra tag like source_id in the `%input#types` so that i can associate each type to the source-id . For example

```
 %input#types{:source_id = source-1 , :name => "types[]", :type => "checkbox", :value=> type2 , checked: :true, readonly: "readonly"}/
```

here `source_id` is `source-1` is `type2` belongs to `source-1` .

is there a simpler way of doing this than having to do `@types.map{|k,v|k if v.include?type}-[nil]` inside the tag in haml

I would also be able to access the `source_id` in the controller for the selected types

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- @types.each do |source,types|
  - types.each do |type|
    - if @sources.include? type
      %input#types{ :source_id => source, :name => "types[]", :type => "checkbox", :value=> "#{type}", checked: :true, readonly: "readonly"}/
      %label{:for => "types"} "#{type}"
    - else
      %input#types{ :source_id => source, :name => "types[]", :type => "checkbox", :value=> "#{type}"}/
      %label{:for => "types"} "#{type}"
```